# Get Client Machine Name in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, client

How do I get the client (not the server) machine name in Rails from a controller? I've tried `Socket.gethostname`but that just get's the name of the server the Rails app is running on. `Resolv.getname(request.remote_ip)` just gives back an error saying there is no name for the client's IP address. I'm on Rails v4 if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using `Resolv`, I ended up doing this, as it is not always possible to retrieve the name of a machine from an ip address:

```
  dns_lookup = ""
  begin
    dns_lookup = Resolv.getname(request.remote_ip)
  rescue Resolv::ResolvError => e
  end
```

Comment: I did say that I already used the `Resolv.getname(request.remote_ip)` command but I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: I tested this out and for some reason I can only get the name from a static IP.

Comment: Are you able to resolve the name using directly `nslookup xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` ?

Comment: It's the same thing with Resolv. nslookup only works on a static IP.